# Searching for end removing crontab jobs

Tags: cron

I want to check to see if the line exists with a script:

`*/2 * * * * ls -1 /var/www/html/shared-media > /var/www/html/files.txt`

I also need a way to remove that SPECIFIC line in the same script.

Comment: `crontab -e`?  ..

Comment: I iknow I can use that, I need this to be run in a script. I'll add that to my post.